# how to put an image inside a flowchart or at a corner of a diagram

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, flow-charts

so i m willing to get something similar to this [image]

but somehow for my lack of expertise about latex so I have this code

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\definecolor{cola}{HTML}{F23030}
\definecolor{colb}{HTML}{F28705}
\definecolor{colc}{HTML}{F29F05}
\definecolor{cold}{HTML}{F2CB05}
\definecolor{cole}{HTML}{267365}
\tikzset{
    customshape/.style={
      lightgray!50,
      line width=0.1cm,
      arrows={-Stealth }
    },
mybox/.style={
      rectangle,
      rounded corners=0.25cm,
      text width=6cm,
      minimum height=1.5cm,
      minimum width=8cm,
      fill=lightgray,
      text=white,
      font=\rmfamily\bfseries,
      draw=white,
      line width=2pt,
      align=center}}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mybox,fill=cola ] (A){\MakeUppercase{Input Images}}; 
\node[mybox,fill=colb,below right=0.2cm and -5cm of A] (B) { \MakeUppercase{Extraction of image representation}};
\node[mybox,fill=colc,below right=0.2cm and -5cm of B] (C) {\MakeUppercase{Representation scheme}};
\node[mybox,fill=cold,below right=0.2cm and -5cm of C] (D) {\MakeUppercase{Analysis;Interpretation;\\Understranding}};
\node[mybox,fill=cole,below right=0.2cm and -5cm of D] (E) {\MakeUppercase{decision and result}};


\draw[customshape,cola!20] ([xshift=0.4cm]A.south west) |- (B.mid west);
\draw[customshape,colb!20] ([xshift=0.4cm]B.south   west) |- (C.west);
\draw[customshape,colc!20] ([xshift=0.4cm]C.south west) |- (D.west);
\draw[customshape,cold!20] ([xshift=0.4cm]D.south west) |- (E.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The initial stage of visual recognition is object detection.}
\label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you re-use the code from other peoples answers it would be nice if you would at least mention where you got the code from :(

Comment: i thought of it but i didn't know how to mention you . how to mention someone so i give the people credits in the future .pardon me because i m blue

Comment: At the very minimum, you should add a link to the answer where you got the code from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the image as a `path picture`. Once the `A` node is defined, place your image with the command:

`\node[blue, mycircle=example-image-duck] at (A.north east){};`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\definecolor{cola}{HTML}{F23030}
\definecolor{colb}{HTML}{F28705}
\definecolor{colc}{HTML}{F29F05}
\definecolor{cold}{HTML}{F2CB05}
\definecolor{cole}{HTML}{267365}
\tikzset{
    customshape/.style={
      lightgray!50,
      line width=0.1cm,
      arrows={-Stealth }},
    mybox/.style={
      rectangle,
      rounded corners=0.25cm,
      text width=6cm,
      minimum height=1.5cm,
      minimum width=8cm,
      fill=lightgray,
      text=white,
      font=\rmfamily\bfseries,
      draw=white,
      line width=2pt,
      align=center},
    mycircle/.style={
      draw, 
      circle, 
      line width=3pt, 
      inner sep=0pt, 
      minimum size=1cm, 
      path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center){\includegraphics[height=1cm]{#1}};}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mybox,fill=cola ] (A){\MakeUppercase{Input Images}}; 
  \node[blue, mycircle=example-image-duck] at (A.north east){};
\node[mybox,fill=colb,below right=0.2cm and -5cm of A] (B) { \MakeUppercase{Extraction of image representation}};
\node[mybox,fill=colc,below right=0.2cm and -5cm of B] (C) {\MakeUppercase{Representation scheme}};
\node[mybox,fill=cold,below right=0.2cm and -5cm of C] (D) {\MakeUppercase{Analysis;Interpretation;\\Understranding}};
\node[mybox,fill=cole,below right=0.2cm and -5cm of D] (E) {\MakeUppercase{decision and result}};


\draw[customshape,cola!20] ([xshift=0.4cm]A.south west) |- (B.mid west);
\draw[customshape,colb!20] ([xshift=0.4cm]B.south   west) |- (C.west);
\draw[customshape,colc!20] ([xshift=0.4cm]C.south west) |- (D.west);
\draw[customshape,cold!20] ([xshift=0.4cm]D.south west) |- (E.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The initial stage of visual recognition is object detection.}
\label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```