# controll over shapes and image + tikz add path image background

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, tikz-shape, tikz-shadings

code used and efforts made are referred in here :[link 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712251/modified-planet-outline-and-orbitals-in-smartdiagram),[link 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712183/how-to-put-an-image-inside-a-flowchart-or-at-a-corner-of-a-diagram)
I ended up updating this code but the  **facing errors**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, fontsize}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shapes.misc, shadings, fadings}
\tikzset{
    mybox/.style={
        rounded rectangle ,rounded rectangle east arc=concave, 
%       rounded corners=2cm,
        text width=4cm,
        minimum height=2.5cm,
        fill=lightgray,
        text=white,
        font=\rmfamily\bfseries,
        line width=2pt,
        align=center},
    mycircle/.style={circle,minimum height=2cm,
    align=center, path picture={
        \node[anchor=center, top color={##2},bottom color={##3}, circle, minimum size=2cm, inner sep=0pt](ZZ) at (path picture bounding box.center){};
        \node at (path picture bounding ZZ.center){\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{#1}};
        }},}

\tikzset{fontscale/.style = {font=\relsize{#1}}
}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [postaction={path fading=north,fill=white}]
                        [postaction={path fading=south,fading angle=-45,fill=lightgray,opacity=.8}]
                            [left color=Green,right color=Green3,draw=white, line width=5mm]
%
                (0,0)circle  [radius=4cm] 
                    node[align=center, , Chartreuse4] (A) 
                        {\Hugerrr\bfseries Image\\ \fontsize{40}{50}\selectfont Processing};
\node[mybox,
                        fill=DeepSkyBlue3,xshift=-3cm 
                        ] 
                        at (150:6cm) (A){Image \\classification};
\node[blue, mycircle=example-image-duck ,top color=pink,red] 
at ([xshift=0.2cm,yshift=-4pt]A.mid east){};
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{The initial stage of visual recognition is object detection.}
        \label{fig:enter-label}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

**meanwhile what I m looking for is something like this :[image: Image Desired]**

**The code is compiling but I m having 9 errors and I don't want to ignore its probably because I set 3 arguments and I call them or mention them properly**

Answer (score 3):

for the shape of the surroundings ready made `rounded rectangle` is available in `Tikz` - you have to only add `east arc = concave` - the spacing you can easily adjust with `xshift` and `yshift`

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{
    mybox/.style={
        rounded rectangle ,rounded rectangle east arc=concave, 
%       rounded corners=2cm,
        text width=4cm,
        minimum height=1.7cm,
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        fill=lightgray,
        text=white,
        font=\rmfamily\bfseries,
        draw=white,
        line width=2pt,
        align=center},
    mycircle/.style={
        draw=white, 
        circle, 
        line width=3pt, 
        inner sep=16pt, 
        path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{#1}};}},
    cir/.style ={circle,align=center,minimum width=5cm,fill=Pink},
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            
            \node[mybox,fill=DeepSkyBlue3 ] at (120:6cm) (A){Image \\classification};
            \node[blue, mycircle=example-image-duck, draw=black,  ] at ([xshift=0.2cm,yshift=-4pt]A.mid east){};
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{The initial stage of visual recognition is object detection.}
        \label{fig:enter-label}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}`
```

**EDIT** to include the central circle with shading

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, fontsize}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shapes.misc, shadings, fadings}
\tikzset{
    mybox/.style={
        rounded rectangle ,rounded rectangle east arc=concave, 
%       rounded corners=2cm,
        text width=4cm,
        minimum height=1.7cm,
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        fill=lightgray,
        text=white,
        font=\rmfamily\bfseries,
        draw=white,
        line width=2pt,
        align=center},
    mycircle/.style={
        draw=white, 
        circle, 
        line width=3pt, 
        inner sep=16pt, 
        path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{#1}};}},
%   cir/.style ={circle,align=center,minimum width=5cm,fill=Pink},
}
\usepackage{relsize}

\tikzset{fontscale/.style = {font=\relsize{#1}}
}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [postaction={path fading=south,fill=white}]
                        [postaction={path fading=south,fading angle=-45,fill=blue,opacity=.5}]
                            [left color=blue,right color=white,draw=white, line width=6mm]
%
                (0,0)circle  [radius=8em] 
                    node[align=center, , black!40!blue] (A) 
                        {\Hugerrr\bfseries Image\\ \fontsize{40}{30}\selectfont Processing};
            \node[
                        mybox,
                        fill=DeepSkyBlue3 
                        ] 
                        at (120:6cm) (A){Image \\classification};
            \node[
                        blue, 
                        mycircle=example-image-duck, 
                        draw=black,  
                        ] 
                        at ([xshift=0.2cm,yshift=-4pt]A.mid east){};
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{The initial stage of visual recognition is object detection.}
        \label{fig:enter-label}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2** - in response to the comments of the OP - `can you please check code ,and tell me what can i do to not have errors`

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, fontsize}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shapes.misc, shadings, fadings}
\tikzset{
    mybox/.style={
        rounded rectangle ,
        rounded rectangle east arc=concave, 
        text width=4cm,
        minimum height=1.7cm,
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        fill=lightgray,
        text=white,
        font=\rmfamily\bfseries,
        draw=white,
        line width=2pt,
        align=center},
    mycircle/.style={
        circle, 
        line width=3pt, 
        inner sep=16pt, 
        path picture={
            \node at (path picture bounding box.center){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{#1}};}}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw 
            [postaction={
                                    path fading=south,
                                    fill=white}]
            [postaction={
                                    path fading=south,
                                    fading angle=-45,
                                    fill=blue,
                                    opacity=.5}]
            [left color=blue,
            right color=white,
            draw=white, 
            line width=6mm]
            
            
            (0,0)circle  [radius=8em] 
            node[
                    align=center, 
                    black!40!blue] 
                    (A) 
            {\Hugerrr\bfseries Image\\ \fontsize{40}{30}\selectfont Processing};
            
            \node[
            mybox,
            fill=DeepSkyBlue3 
            ] 
            at (150:8cm) (B){Image \\classification};
            
            \node[
            mycircle=example-image-duck, 
            draw=blue,  
            ] 
            at (B.east){};
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{The initial stage of visual recognition is object detection.}
        \label{fig:enter-label}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: that works perfectly and how to make that shading at the center circle and that multi-font

Comment: i m looking to make a shading for the outline of the drawing line for the picture holder

Comment: @BROK code has been edited for the center circle

Comment: can you please check code ,and tell me what can i do to not have errors

Comment: @BROK please see your code has been corrected in the `EDIT 2` above

Comment: thnx i already fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Just because of how challenging the result is, here is an arrangement to obtain a result that is a little more faithful to what is required, only with the detail that the colors used with the shadings environment differ from the fill environment, it would be good to ask why that happens. The usual formula is to make objects with the necessary properties and then be able to even nest them, reuse them, in short I hope the code is readable.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light,condensed]{roboto} 
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds,ducks,calc,shadings}
\definecolor{BG}{HTML}{F6FAFE}
\definecolor{SB}{HTML}{797d90}
\definecolor{C1}{HTML}{6EA3D1}
\definecolor{C2}{HTML}{004688}
\definecolor{C3}{HTML}{003161}
\definecolor{C4}{HTML}{FE9100}
\definecolor{C5}{HTML}{CA4D52}
\definecolor{C6}{HTML}{9E3D5B}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=BG}, show background rectangle]
        
    \def\ShadeButton(#1)[#2][#3][#4]#5#6{
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
            \shade[left color=#5, right color=white,shading angle=135] (0,0) circle (#2);
            \shade[left color=#5, right color=white,shading angle=-45] (0,0) circle (#2-1.5mm);
            \path [path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \shade[outer color=#5, inner color=white,shading = radial] (0mm,0mm) circle (#2*5);
                        \path(0,0) -- (-6.5*#2,-6.5*#2);
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                };}](0,0) circle (#2-3mm)node[align=center,xscale=#3,yscale=#4]{#6};
        \end{scope}
    }

    \def\Sat(#1)[#2][#3][#4]#5#6#7#8{
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},xscale=#4]
            \shade[shading angle=135] (0,0) circle (#2);
            \fill[#5,opacity=0.5] (0,0) circle (#2);
            \fill[#5,opacity=0.5] (0,0) circle (#2);
            \path [path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \shade[outer color=black!50!BG, inner color=white,shading = radial] (0mm,0mm) circle (#2*5);
                        \path(0,0) -- (-6.5*#2,-6.5*#2);
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                };}](0,0) circle (#2-3mm);
            \fill[#5](180-55:#2+3mm) arc(180-55:180+55:#2+3mm)-- ++(-15em,0) arc (180+55:180-55:#2+3mm) -- cycle;
            \draw (-9em-#2/2,0)node[align=center,xscale=#3*0.9,yscale=#3*1,font=\bf,text=white]{#6};
            \draw (0,0)node[scale=#7, align=center]{#8};
        \end{scope}
    }

    \def\DUCK{% TO PUT DUCKS IN NODES
        \begin{tikz}
            \tikz\shuffleducks\duck[\randomhead,scale=0.3];
            \tikz\shuffleducks\duck[\randomhead,scale=0.3,xshift=1cm];
            \tikz\shuffleducks\duck[\randomhead,scale=0.3,xshift=-1cm];
        \end{tikz}
    }

    % Start drawing the thing
    
    \ShadeButton(0,0)[27mm][1.6][1.3]{SB!100!SB}{\Huge\bf IMAGE\\ \ttfamily Processing}
    \Sat(180-60:5)[14mm][2][1]{C1}{Image \\ clasification}{1}{\DUCK}
    \Sat(180:5)[14mm][2][1]{C2}{Object \\ detection And \\ localization}{4}{\faSearch}
    \Sat(180+60:5)[14mm][1.6][1]{C3}{Image \\ segmentation \\ and object \\recognition}{0.7}{\DUCK \\ \DUCK \\ \DUCK}
    \Sat(60:5)[14mm][2][-1]{C4}{Image \\ understanding\\ and analysis}{1}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \path [path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \tikz\shuffleducks\duck[\randomhead,scale=1];
                \end{tikzpicture}
            };}](0,0) circle (10.9mm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \Sat(0:5)[14mm][2][-1]{C5}{Image \\ Generation \\ and Synthesis}{1}{\includegraphics[height=12mm]{example-image-a}}
    \Sat(-60:5)[14mm][2][-1]{C6}{Image \\ Restoration And \\ Enhancement}{1}{\includegraphics[height=12mm]{example-image-duck}}
    
    % Adendum
    
    \ShadeButton(-90:8)[20mm][2.1][1.2]{cyan!50!green!70!black}{\Huge NOD\\ \rmfamily JX5893\\ \tiny not enigmatic \\[-1em] \tiny content}
    \Sat($(-90:8)+(180:3.5)$)[10mm][1.8][1]{cyan!50!green!70!black}{another position \\ using calc}{0.5}{\DUCK}
    \Sat($(-90:8)+(0:3.5)$)[10mm][1.8][-1]{cyan!20!green!70!black}{another position \\ using xscale=-1}{0.5}{\DUCK}
            
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Note: Some ducks may vary, there may be multiple encoding warnings but it is due to the use of fontawesome, using other fonts can solve it.